# Is there a way to block Ultrasurf OR can I have McAfee nuke it?

Tags: proxy

I'm working for a high school. We have given every student their own laptop. Some of our students have figured out how to bypass our web filter using a program called Ultrasurf.

If you're not familiar with it, Ultrasurf is sort of like a proxy service. It basically goes online and downloads a large list of proxy servers from a google docs file and then randomly connects to one. We obviously can't block Google docs. It tends to use port 443 so we obviously can't block that without using HTTPS and the list of host it downloads is too long to filter all of them.

Is there any way of blocking it?

If not, I had another idea. Since these are **our** laptops, we have some degree of control over the software. We use McAfee's enterprise AV software. I'm not an expert when it comes to McAfee. Is it possible to create a custom signature for McAfee? If so, can we create a signature so that McAfee will think this program is malicious and simply delete it every time it is downloaded? We don't see much Tor activity but I assume such a trick would also let us gut Tor if our students learn about it.

Comment: Hello Monsuco and welcome to Security.SE. Unfortunately it almost impossible to protect computers to which adversaries have physical access to. Furthermore, your adversaries have a lot of time, motivation and probably technology skills. I suggest to approach this issue from a social angle: Create a set of rules for acceptable use of school property with realistic (!) consequences for concrete types of misuse.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, setup Rules, let your student sign these rules, and then BANG those guys'n'girls who are doing workarounds (or let them pay for professional virus-desinfection :)

the other (right) way is to use a transparent proxy on your firewall that filters http/https - traffic. on thta transparent proxy you can whitelist/blacklist.

and you MUST  block outgoing requests, if not via transparent proxy.

hw-firewalls usually have this feature, and also the ability to use category-based webfilters

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: if you do this wrong or add an aggressive rule eg.**\Users***.exe you can break your entire environment

you can block the install file, exactable and\or the install path.

from https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB81095

How to create a user-defined Access Protection rule for file/folder blocking

VSE 8.x console
1.  Click Start, Programs, McAfee, VirusScan Console.
2.  Double-click Access Protection.
3.  Under Categories, click User-Defined Rules, then New.
4.  Select File/Folder Blocking Rule, then click OK.
5.  In the File/Folder Blocking rule box, changes the following:
a.  Rule name. Type the name of your rule.
b.  Processes to include. Type an asterisk (*) unless you want to prevent   only specific processes. An asterisk (*) specifies all processes.
c.  Processes to exclude. Type the process to exclude. Separate each process with a comma and a space.
d.  File or Folder name to block. Type or browse to the file name or path name you want to protect. For more information about using wildcards,
e.  At the bottom, select the actions that you want to prevent.
6.  Click OK.
After you have saved your rule, select Block and Report or Report, as required
7.  Click Apply, then OK.

ePO 5.x console

1. Log into the ePO console.
2. Click Menu, Policy Catalog.
3. From the Product drop-down menu, select either VirusScan Enterprise 8.8 or VirusScan Enterprise 8.7.
4. From the Category drop-down menu, select Access Protection Policies.
5. Click the policy where you want to add the new user-defined Access Protection Rule.
6. From the drop-down menu at the top of the page, select either Workstation or Server.
7. Under Categories, click User-Defined Rules, then New.
8. Select File/Folder Blocking Rule, then click OK.
9. In the File/Folder Blocking rule box, changes the following:
   a.  Rule name. Type the name of your rule.
   b.  Processes to include. Type an asterisk (*) unless you want to prevent only specific processes. An asterisk (*) specifies all processes.
   c.  Processes to exclude. Type the process to exclude. Separate each process with a comma and a space.
   d.  File or Folder name to block. Type or browse to the file name or path name you want to protect. For more information about using wildcards,
   e.  At the bottom, select the actions that you want to prevent.
10. Click OK.
    After you have saved your rule, select Block and Report or Report, as required
11. Click Apply, then OK.

regards,